# Drastic legibility difference between python's imshow and savefig

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure()  
plt.imshow(gray)
plt.show()
fig.savefig("woohoo.png", dpi=100)
```

what imshow() pops up as the image is way better quality and legible compared to the file woohoo.png.

I tried increasing the dpi but there is such a huge difference that is the file saved files to even be legible.

What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to create the  figure already with a higher dpi: `fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)`, for example...